# PostgreSQL/QGIS converting long/lat to suitable projection/SRID

Tags: qgis, postgresql, latitude-longitude, srid, pgadmin-3

I have a set of UK postcode data that I have converted into latitude and longitude. I also have a UK counties shapefile.

The code that I have used to convert the latitude/longitude to a geometry point column is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE colic ADD COLUMN longlat geometry(POINT,27700);
update colic set longlat = st_setsrid(st_point( longitude, latitude), 27700);
```

And this produces a column that has values as follows (I've only included a couple!):

> "0101000020346C000048BF7D1D3867E83FC05B2041F1334A40"
> "0101000020346C0000F085C954C1A8F7BFA1F831E6AE954A40"
> "0101000020346C000020D26F5F07CEF4BFE3361AC05B504A40"
> "0101000020346C00007D3F355EBA49F73FB6847CD0B3614A40"

The .prj from my shapefile is:

> PROJCS["British_National_Grid", GEOGCS["GCS_OSGB_1936",
> DATUM["D_OSGB_1936", SPHEROID["Airy_1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]],
> PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
> PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
> PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000.0],
> PARAMETER["False_Northing",-100000.0],
> PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-2.0],
> PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996012717],
> PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49.0], UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

And I set its SRID to 27700 when I upload it using the PostGIS shapefile uploader.

In PG Admin, when I ask:

```
select st_srid(geom) from counties limit 1;
select st_srid(longlat) from colic limit 1;
```

I get 27700 for both.

But... when I try any spatial query I get no response, and when I load the layers into QGIS, the point data are off the tip of Cornwall in the North Atlantic, and only represented as one dot on the scale of the counties map.

[image]

If I zoom in on them, they are 'there', but just not in East Anglia where they should be!

[image]

This is my first attempt at both SQL and mapping.